# NSXmlParser foundCharacters method is not reading words in one time?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

NSXmlParser foundCharacters method is not reading string in one time when characters coming with special characters like København which is a danish word???

It breaks it from ø and read it separately...

Answer (score 3):

What's your question? This is documented behavior:

> The parser object may send the delegate several parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an element. Because string may be only part of the total character content for the current element, you should append it to the current accumulation of characters until the element changes.

If you wish to capture the entire textual contents of a tag, you'll have to catch all these messages and join the contents in a string.